# How can I read the CVPixelBuffer as 4 channel float format from a CIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, metal, core-image, coreml

I'm currently trying to do some calculations on a CIImage construct. We are using a custom Core ML model on video frames, and in the meantime using GPU to translate these with CIFilters to required formats.

For one step, I need to do some calculations on two of the outputs generated by a model, and find the mean and standart deviations from the pixel data per channel.

For testing and tech preview, I was able to create a UIImage, read CVPixelData, convert and calculate on the CPU. But while trying to adapt it to the GPU I hit a rock.

The process is simple:

- Convert CIImage BGRA to LAB format. We do not need the alpha channel, but kept as LAB-A
- Do calculations on the pixel data.
- Return from LAB to BGRA, and copy the alpha channel as is.

At current state, I am using a custom CIFilter + Metal kernel to convert the CIImage from RGB to LAB (and back to RGB) format. Without calculations in between, RGB > LAB > RGB conversion works as expected and returns the same image without any deformations. This tells me that the float precision is not lost.

But when I tried to read the pixel data in between, I'm not able to get the float values I was looking for. CVPixelBuffer created from the LAB formatted CIImage is giving me values that are always zero. Tried a few different OSType formats like `kCVPixelFormatType_64RGBAHalf`, `kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat`, `kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB`, etc., none of them are returning the float values. But if I read data from another image I'm always getting the UInt8 values as expected...

So my question is as the title suggest "**How can I read the CVPixelBuffer as a 4 channel float format from a CIImage?**"

Simplified Swift and Metal code for the process is as follows.

```swift
let ciRgbToLab = CIConvertRGBToLAB() // CIFilter using metal for kernel
let ciLabToRgb = CIConvertLABToRGB() // CIFilter using metal for kernel

ciRgbToLab.inputImage = source // "source" is a CIImage
guard let sourceLab = ciRgbToLab.outputImage else { throw ... }

ciRgbToLab.inputImage = target // "target" is a CIImage
guard let targetLab = ciRgbToLab.outputImage { throw ... }

// Get the CVPixelBuffer and lock the data.
guard let sourceBuffer = sourceLab.cvPixelBuffer else { throw ... }
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(sourceBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
defer {
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(sourceBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
}

// Access to the data
guard let sourceAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(sourceBuffer) { throw ... }
let sourceDataSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(sourceBuffer)
let sourceData = sourceAddress.bindMemory(to: CGFloat.self, capacity: sourceDataSize)
// ... do calculations
// ... generates a new CIImage named "targetTransfered"

ciLabToRgb.inputImage = targetTransfered //*
guard let rgbFinal = ciLabToRgb.outputImage else  { throw ... }

//* If "targetTransfered" is replaced with "targetLab", we get the exact image as "target".
```

```cpp
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

extern "C" {
  namespace coreimage {
    float4 xyzToLabConversion(float4 pixel) {
      ...
      return float4(l, a, b, pixel.a);
    }
    
    float4 rgbToXyzConversion(float4 pixel) {
      ...
      return float4(x, y, z, pixel.a);
    }
    
    float4 rgbToLab(sample_t s) {
      float4 xyz = rgbToXyzConversion(s);
      float4 lab = xyzToLabConversion(xyz);
      return lab;
    }
    
    float4 xyzToRgbConversion(float4 pixel) {
      ...
      return float4(R, G, B, pixel.a);
    }
    
    float4 labToXyzConversion(float4 pixel) {
      ...
      return float4(X, Y, Z, pixel.a);
    }
    
    float4 labtoRgb(sample_t s) {
      float4 xyz = labToXyzConversion(s);
      float4 rgb = xyzToRgbConversion(xyz);
      return rgb;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the extension I'm using to convert CIImage to CVPixelBuffer. As the image is created on device by the same source, it is always in BGRA format. I have no idea how to convert this to get float values...

```swift
extension CIImage {
    var cvPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? {
    let attrs = [
                  kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue,
                  kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue,
                  kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue
                ] as CFDictionary

    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                     Int(self.extent.width),
                                     Int(self.extent.height),
                                     kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                     attrs,
                                     &pixelBuffer)

    guard status == kCVReturnSuccess else { return nil }
    guard let buffer = pixelBuffer else { return nil }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.init(rawValue: 0))

    let context = CIContext()
    context.render(self, to: buffer)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    return pixelBuffer
  }
}
```

*PS: I removed the metal kernel code to fit in here. If you need a RGB > LAB > RGB conversion, send me a message, I'm happy to share the  filter.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very strange that you get all zeros, especially when you set the format to `kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat`...

However, I highly recommend you check out [CIImageProcessorKernel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimageprocessorkernel#), it's made for this very use case: adding custom (potentially CPU-based) processing steps to a Core Image pipeline. In the `process` function you get access to the input and output buffers either as `MTLTexture`, `CVPixelBuffer`, or even direct access to the `baseAddress`.

Here is an example kernel I wrote for computing the mean and variance of the input image using Metal Performance Shaders and returning them in a 2x1 pixel `CIImage`:

```
import CoreImage
import MetalPerformanceShaders


/// Processing kernel that computes the mean and the variance of a given image and stores
/// those values in a 2x1 pixel return image.
class MeanVarianceKernel: CIImageProcessorKernel {

    override class func roi(forInput input: Int32, arguments: [String : Any]?, outputRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // we need to read the full extend of the input
        return arguments?["inputExtent"] as? CGRect ?? outputRect
    }

    override class var outputFormat: CIFormat {
        return .RGBAf
    }

    override class var synchronizeInputs: Bool {
        // no need to wait for CPU synchronization since the processing is also happening on the GPU
        return false
    }

    /// Convenience method for calling the `apply` method from outside.
    class func apply(to input: CIImage) -> CIImage {
        // pass the extent of the input as argument since we need to know the full extend in the ROI callback above
        return try! self.apply(withExtent: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 1), inputs: [input], arguments: ["inputExtent": input.extent])
    }

    override class func process(with inputs: [CIImageProcessorInput]?, arguments: [String : Any]?, output: CIImageProcessorOutput) throws {
        guard
            let commandBuffer = output.metalCommandBuffer,
            let input = inputs?.first,
            let sourceTexture = input.metalTexture,
            let destinationTexture = output.metalTexture
        else {
            return
        }

        let meanVarianceShader = MPSImageStatisticsMeanAndVariance(device: commandBuffer.device)
        meanVarianceShader.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceTexture: sourceTexture, destinationTexture: destinationTexture)
    }

}
```

It can easily be added to a filter pipeline like this:

```
let meanVariance: CIImage = MeanVarianceKernel.apply(to: inputImage)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely look into this when I return back to the code. I see that your kernel partitions the image and processes on different threads. You are using the extend to make sure it processes once. So output image can be used as a holder for scalar variables and I can get the calculations from that. Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: I'm not explicitly partitioning the image and also don't do explicit threading. I'm just using the `MPSImageStatisticsMeanAndVariance`, pass it the input and output texture (which is created by Core Image based in the `withExtent` parameter in `apply` and the `outputFormat`) and encode it into the same Metal command buffer as Core Image does, so it will be queued to the GPU in line with Core Image's other operations.

Comment: Your response pointed me to the right destination thanks . Found out that I could easily move all of my computations into just three metal kernels. As converting CIImage to MTLTexture is as simple as calling a render on CIContext, and everything is already running on GPU, at the end I decided not to use CIImageProcessorKernel as a base class.